# ERROR: operator does not exist : boolean = bytea in spring jpa query and postgres

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

When I execute below query directly in postgres it works fine but when I run with JPA then below error occurs.

**Example Query:**

```
select
    *
from
    products
where
    clientId = :clientId
    and ((:status is null
    and status in (true,
    false))
    or status = :status)
    and ((:anotherStatus is null
    and anotherStatus in (true,
    false))
    or anotherStatus = :anotherStatus);
```

**Error:**

> ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR:
>   operator does not exist: boolean = bytea   Hint: No operator matches
>   the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type
>   casts.

**Configured in JPA like this:**

```
@Query(value="select * from products where clientId = :clientId and ((:status is null and status in (true, false)) or status = :status) and ((:anotherStatus is null and anotherStatus in (true, false)) or anotherStatus = :anotherStatus)",nativeQuery=true)
List<Products> fetchProducts(@Param("clientId") Long clientId, @Param("status") Boolean status, @Param("anotherStatus") Boolean anotherStatus);
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is, When user sends param as `true` filter products with `true` (active) or as `false` (in active), and when user don't send anything (which is `null`) then fetch all products (`true` and `false`)

Comment: `:status is null` and `:anotherStatus is null` is not supported as far I know

Comment: @Eklavya - Is not supported in JPA ?, So how do I really achieve this...Could you please help me

Comment: It may not supported in SQL, use JPA specification for searching

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that `null = null`, `true = null` and `false = null` all evaluate to `null`, which is treated as `false` in a `where`-clause. If you want anything else, please rephrase your question.
Let's look at a truth table for `(:status is null and status in (true,false)) or status = :status`.

```
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|   :status   |   status    |   result    |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|    null     |    null     |    false    |
|    null     |    true     |    true     |
|    null     |    false    |    true     |
|    true     |    null     |    false    |
|    true     |    true     |    true     |
|    true     |    false    |    false    |
|    false    |    null     |    false    |
|    false    |    true     |    false    |
|    false    |    false    |    true     |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
```

In other words, you want a clause that always returns `false` when `status` is `null`. This leaves `true` when `:status` is `null`, or true if `:status` and `status` have the same value.

`status is not null and (:status is null or status = :status)`

alternatively,

`status is not null and coalesce(:status, status) = status`

Note that this still fails for the error you describe, because `:status` is bound as a `BYTEA` by Hibernate when you pass `null` in Java. You can work around this by doing a double cast.

`CAST(CAST(:status AS CHARACTER VARYING) AS BOOLEAN)`

If this is what you intended, the resulting query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE status IS NOT NULL
AND anotherStatus IS NOT NULL
AND COALESCE(CAST(CAST(:status AS CHARACTER VARYING) AS BOOLEAN), status) = status
AND COALESCE(CAST(CAST(:anotherStatus AS CHARACTER VARYING) AS BOOLEAN), anotherStatus) = anotherStatus
```

Comment: ` COALESCE(CAST(CAST(:status AS CHARACTER VARYING) AS BOOLEAN), status) = status` my hero.